# How to set a Master Workbooks Object?

Tags: excel, vba

I was thinking if its possible to set a Master Workbook in Excel VBA and access it on all procedures and functions?

Since I am pretty new to VBA I don't understand the syntax VBA is using..

```
Dim MasterWB as Workbook
Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open("Path to my Workbook")
```

But if I want to access it in an another Procedure or Function I'll get a Object Definition Error.

I don't want to declare the Object in every Sub or Function.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

The good practice:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim MasterWB As Workbook
    Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open("Path")
    UseWb MasterWB

End Sub
Sub UseWb(wb As Workbook)

    wb.Close

End Sub
```

The you shouldn't use practice:

```
Option Explicit
Public MasterWB As Workbook
Sub Test()

    Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open("Path")
    UseWb MasterWB

End Sub
Sub UseWb()

    wb.Close

End Sub
```

The first one allows you to pass the `Workbook Variable` as parameter to other functions in this case you can't use `ByVal` but other variables like `Integer`or `Long` can be used as `ByVal` instead of (per default) `ByRef`.

`ByVal` means you are only passing the value of that variable, so you won't modify it on the function.

`ByRef` means you pass the reference, so the other function can modify that original variable.

The second way only allows you to use the variable as a reference so there might be changes on it without noticing.

Hope this clears out a bit your question.

Comment: with object parameters you _can_ use ByVal, since it's the pointer to the object that's passed by value.  You can modify the object that the pointer points to.  What you _can't_ do is modify the pointer itself to point to some other object